# Delphi - How to get service ObjectID from class TAndroidService?

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-10-seattle

Does anyone know how to get service ObjectID (JNI Object) or JService from TAndroidService in Delphi?

Thank you very much for your advice and answers.

Comment: Why do you need to get JService from TAndroidService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TAndroidService` inherits from `TAndroidBaseService`, which has a property called `JavaService` of type `JService`. So something like:

```
uses
  Androidapi.JNI.App;
...
var
  ServiceIntf: JService;
...
ServiceIntf := MyService.JavaService;
```

If you want the JNI object, try casting `JavaService` as `ILocalObject` and calling the `GetObjectID` method:

```
uses
  Androidapi.Jni;
...
var
  ServiceObjectID: JNIObject;
...
ServiceObjectID := (ServiceIntf as ILocalObject).GetObjectID; // gets the JNI ObjectID
```